# Selecting another radio button inside OnClick event

Tags: delphi

I have two radio buttons rdoA & rdoB. My requirement is whenever user clicks rdoA, I have to check certain parameters and if those are not satisfied revert the selection to rdoB. I have the code like this

```
MyForm.rdoAClick
var
  Save: TNotifyEvent;
begin
 if //some condition then
 begin
     Save := rdoB.OnClick;
     rdoB.OnClick := nil;
     rdoB.Checked := true;
     rdoB.OnClick := Save;
     Exit;
 End;
 //Other stuff
End;
```

The problem is this code works but in certain scenario say when rdoB is selected already and if we change it to rdoA and if the condition satisfies rdoB is selected back and if i switch the focus of the window and comes back to the form rdoAClick event is triggered again.

What am i doing wrong here? Is there any better way to solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to check some condition in another place (when some event happens) and disable radio button?

Comment: Yes, why are you letting the user click at all?

Comment: *"if i switch the focus of the window and comes back to the form rdoAClick event is triggered again."* Might be related to this: [The Hidden Dangers of TRadioButton.TabStop](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/02/02/37987/) and this: [RadioGroup.TabStop doesn't control whether radio buttons receive focus](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=1860).  It is just a quirk in how RadioGroups handle input focus.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have simplifed the scenario. Actually in the click we popup a message asking whether user wants to proceed making changes. If user clicks yes we will go ahead and do it, if no then we will not make those changes and revert back to the previous radio selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was once fighting a similar issue and found the solution to be (adapted to your code)

```
procedure TForm6.rdoAClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  save: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  if MessageDlg('Allow change?',mtConfirmation, [mbYes,mbNo],0) = mrNo then
  begin
    save := rdoB.OnClick;
    rdoB.OnClick := nil;
    rdoB.SetFocus;
//    rdoB.Checked := True;
    rdoB.OnClick := save;
  end;
end;
```

Setting Focus instead of Checked (which becomes set anyway as a result of setting Focus) assures the RadioButton is in correct internal state.